# Bug or by design? The tag engine of doom and search

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or whether it is by design.

When you search for something that you have flagged not to see, the questions disappear appear from the results page. I assume this is because they have a tag that I have hidden.

Example, I have MySQL hidden from the main questions and Sql-Server as a favourite tag. Earlier, I searched for a post that had Sql-Server and MySQL in the tags, and the questions were hidden.

In my opinion, if I have searched for something that is in my "hidden" list, the results should appear.

Simple re-pro, search for two tags in the same seach, one in your favourite list the other in your hidden list and see what happens.

**Note:** Thanks to the first comment, I might have made my self unclear. You need to add a search term in after the tags. Eg:  [mysql] [sql-server] connection where mysql is ignored, sql-server is a favourite.

Like I said, this is probably by design, but it could be a bug; it's hard to tell.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I tried two different tag combinations, and in both cases, as intended when explicityly searching for a tag that's in the ignore list, the questions did show up.

Comment: @balpha, did you just search for the tags? Try adding something else eg: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bsql-server%5D+connection

Comment: @balpha: I can reproduce it (on SU). Make sure you've checked to hide ignored tags.

Comment: For me it appeared with half transparency so I can't reproduce. Chrome here, maybe it's browser issue?

Comment: @balpha: I take everything back! This is reproducable if you place a wildcard in the ignored tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Chrome here too. Not tried in other browsers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that wasn't by design; the search result page just didn't implement the "explicit search for tag [x], so ignore the tag preferences" logic. This is fixed in the next build.

And while I was at it: Asylum noted in the comments that the behavior isn't quite as expected when you have wildcards in your tag preferences. This is now handled, namely as follows:

Assume you're ignoring `[jquery*]` (of course nobody would do that, but just imagine it), and you have searched for `[jquery-plugin] basic arithmetic`. **So far**, you wouldn't have seen any results, because *every* question on the search result page matches your wildcard ignore. **Now** (next build), your `[jquery*]` ignorance will be ignored (ignore the double ignoring), because it matches one of the searched-for tags.

So results from that page will then *only* be hidden if they also have some other tag that you're ignoring.

Oh, and also: This had nothing whatsoever to do with the [tag engine of doom](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector).

<sub>I can haz bounty?</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and fix :) You can have the bounty in 20 hours :)

Comment: Thanks for that interesting read (your answer and the blog post about the tag engine). Very interesting stuff.

Comment: bounty awarded :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is what I see when searching with one of the tags in my ignore list:

[image: screenshot]

You say you get no results at all?

Comment: The behaviour here is different depending on your user-prefs

Comment: @MarcGravell EDIT: you mean the "hide ignored tag" checkbox in the [prefs tab of profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard?tab=prefs)?

Comment: yes, that exactly

Comment: @MarcGravell, Ahh, I do have "hide ignored tags" checked. Shouldn't you still see the questions if you explicitly search for them?

Comment: So this is obviously by design.. :)